# CollectionView does not reload

Tags: swift, collectionview

When I press the heart button, I delete the trackID value in the cell from the realmdatabase. After deleting it, I declare it to the viewcontroller and send the index number inside the list to the function. Then I sync my list to the incoming list for collectionView. The collectionView does not reload even though the information looks correct. When I look at the tracktitles, it looks correct, but the collectionView is not updated. I defined delegates in viewdidload

```
class BegenilerCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
    @objc func begenClicked(){
    
        print("sil")

        let objectsToDelete = realm.objects(ObjectTrack.self).filter("trackID == %@", trackID)
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(objectsToDelete)
        }
        let myViewController = BegeniYedekViewController()
        
        
        myViewController.collectionViewReload(Int: trackSira, begeniGelen: begeniler)}
 }





class BegeniYedekViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionViewReload(Int: Int, begeniGelen: [TrackData]){
    

    self.begeniler.removeAll()
    
    print(begeniler.count)
    print(self.begeniler)
    self.begeniler = begeniGelen
    print("Silinecek begeni \(begeniler[Int].title)")
    self.begeniler.remove(at: Int)
    
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        for track in self.begeniler{
            print(track.title)
        }
    }}
```